# Mysql trigger remove data before insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

In **php** i issue a **mysqli insert** like:  `insert into parts (PartNo, OrderNumber) VALUES (?,?)`

In my use case the column ***PartNo*** doesn't exist in the **parts** table, i use it only as a reference.

Then, in my trigger on the **parts** table i want to do something like this:

1. store the value of new.PartNo in a temp variable called 'PartNumber';
2. TOTALLY remove new.PartNo so mysql won't try to insert it into the 'parts' table as that column doesn't exist in the 'parts' table;
3. use the variable 'PartNumber' to select a value from another table;
4. insert the returned value in an existing column in the 'parts' table

So, essentialy i want to simplify my insert statement by supplying the **partNo**, whereas the trigger will do the rest so the insert will be properly handled.

My question is: is B) possible and if so, how? Just setting it to **new.PartNo is null** doesn't seem to cut it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible it will try to execute the insert exactly as you write it.
Why don't you first use a select to get the data you want in a variable and then insert that variable in parts table?